# Maximum update depth exceeded. When invoke parent function in child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I want to call parent component function, when child component mount but I get this error:

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

My code is:

```
function Light(props: IProps) {
    let { language } = useContext(LangContext);
    let { noResponse, off, onn } = language == Languages.fa ? fa_Pages.node : en_Pages.node;

    let { node: { status, nodeName, icon, roomName, name, serial } } = props;
    let { backgroundColor, callback, clientId } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!status) {
            let message = `MSG:DAT:${nodeName}-STATUS:STA*END*`;
            let topic = `IHS/${clientId}/${serial}`;

            console.log("callback ", topic, message);
            callback({ topic, message })
        }
    }, [status])
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: It's impossible to confirm the issue based on this example. You need to provide the code for `callback` and `status` from props.

Answer (score 1):

In your `useEffect`, you have a dependency on `status`. This means that the effect will run every time the `status` changes.

If your effect callback changes the `status` value, you might run into an infinite loop (status changes => callback updates status => status changes => ...)